# Ansible playbook to be executed from GIT

Tags: git, ansible

I would like to run a playbook directly from the git repository (without doing a clone). Is that possible?

Comment: Do you understand without a clone you're not having a local copy?

Comment: Do you mean running a playbook from a directory which has already been cloned (and you don't want to pull again)

Or do you mean you want to point directly to a git repository without doing a clone at all? (this doesn't make sense, maybe you don't want to download the entire repository? or what is your objective?)

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Is it possible to run a playbook directly from the git repository?"***

A: Yes, it is possible. [ansible-pull](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html) covers exactly this use-case:

> pulls playbooks from a VCS repo and executes them for the local host.

Comment: But isn't that doing a clone under the hood? How is this different from cloning it first?